# How can I lookup the grammatical type of a word?

Tags: string-manipulation

It seems WordData isn't complete:

```
In[508]:= WordData["Alice", "ConceptWeight"]    
Out[508]= WordData["Alice", "ConceptWeight"]    
In[507]:= WordData["Michael", "ConceptWeight"]
Out[507]= {{"Michael", "Noun"} -> 0.462007}
```

and is sometimes case-sensitive:

```
In[1]:= # -> WordData[#, "PartsOfSpeech"] & /@ {"French"}
Out[1]= {"French" -> {"Noun", "Adjective", "Verb"}}
In[2]:= # -> WordData[#, "PartsOfSpeech"] & /@ {"french"}    
Out[2]= {"french" -> WordData["french", "PartsOfSpeech"]}
```

Can anyone write a function to find out if a word W is a verb or a pronoun or whatever, *for all correctly spelled english words*?

Comment: "french" (uncapitalized) is not a proper English spelling and hence should not be in the dictionary.

Comment: @bill - according to Merriam-Webster, "french" used a a transitive verb although often -- is not necessarily -- capitalized.

Answer (score -1):

Determine the potential "PartsOfSpeech"

```
WordData["cat", "PartsOfSpeech"]
```

{"Noun", "Verb"}

then test for the type

```
! FreeQ[WordData["cat", "PartsOfSpeech"], "Noun"]
! FreeQ[WordData["cat", "PartsOfSpeech"], "Adjective"]
! FreeQ[WordData["cat", "PartsOfSpeech"], "Verb"]
```

True 
   False 
   True

Also see documentation for FreeQ. These tests may be integrated into a simple function, select or case structure.

Comment: There are many English words not in word data, you'll need to use another source.